# issue pushing a new view controller from a UiView programmatically

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, pushviewcontroller, didselectrowatindexpath

I am trying to present a message viewController after pressing a button that is inside of a UiView. When I press the button, the message viewController presents itself, but it is missing some data. I have a separate viewController that allows me to push the controller. I will leave pictures below to show what I am talking about.

This is what the message view controller is supposed to look like, and this what the code looks like to get there

```
 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dismiss(animated: true) {
        print("Dismiss completed")
        let user = self.user[indexPath.row]
        self.messagesController?.showChatControllerForUser(user)
    }
}
```

[image: Image 1,]

This is what happens when I push the view from the UiView, and this is what the code looks like to get there.

```
        @objc func handleNewMessage() {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
           chatLogController.user = user

    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:chatLogController)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: image 2,]

All of the data pushes through, but the back button is missing, and I am not allowed to actually send a message. I am using two different methods to get to the same controller and I am expecting to see the same result. I was wondering if someone possibly new how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Back button is not displaying because you are presenting the `chatLogController` using below function.

```
@objc func handleNewMessage() {
    let chatLogController = ChatLogController(collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
           chatLogController.user = user

    let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController:chatLogController)
    self.window?.rootViewController?.present(navVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

if you are push to `chatLogController` from `messagesController` then you are display a back button on `chatLogController`.

**Note: back button is automatically display when you push to another `viewController`, it is not display when you present the `viewController`.**

Comment: I am having issues with this suggestion. The only reason I am having trouble with this specific view is because I am not able to access all of the features of the chatLongController when I access it with handleNewMessage. The users name shows in the navbar but when I send a message it crashes. I was thinking that I was missing an initializer in the animation?